# Authenticating Multiple Scopes in Google API Oauth2.0

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client, google-prediction

I need to insert multiple scopes into the http post request that creates the service object that permits authentication. However, simply putting in multiple scopes into the string doesn't seem to achieve this unfortunately, returning the error at the bottom.

```
import gflags
import apiclient
import oauth2client
import argparse
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools
from apiclient import discovery
from apiclient import sample_tools
import httplib2
import sys
import os
import pprint
from pprint import pprint

name = 'prediction'
scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control testing_data/training_data.csv testing_data/training_data.csv"
filename = '__file__'
client_secrets = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename),
                                'client_secrets.json')
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(client_secrets,scope=scope)
storage = file.Storage(name+'.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run(flow, storage)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

service = discovery.build('prediction','v1.6',http=http)

papi = service.trainedmodels()
result = papi.list(maxResults=10,project='895092811023').execute()
body = {'id':'Universities','storageDataLocation':'testing_data/training_data.csv'}
start = papi.insert(body=body,project='895092811023').execute()
```

This is the error, which points out that the required scopes are missing. (It is recording some scope, because it is saving a result to result, but just not letting me insert a new model, which I believe is due to the fact that it isn't getting the scope to access the data for this model, which is in Google Cloud Storage?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filehere", line 42, in <module>
    start = papi.insert(body=body,project='895092811023').execute()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\oauth2client\util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apiclient\http.py", line 680, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.6/projects/895092811023/trainedmodels?alt=json returned "Required scope(s) missing.">
```

Comment: try separating your scopes with a ,

Comment: Separating the scopes with a comma didn't work for me, but separating them with a space did (at least using Swift via the Objective-C API). So `let compositeScope: String = kMyGMailScope + " " + kMyGDriveScope` for example, gave me both Drive and GMail auth with a single login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to pass in for scopes are the www.googleapis.com things such as: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction, don't pass in "testing_data/training_data.csv testing_data/training_data.csv".

You can always visit https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens and see the scopes that your application has been granted.